# MySQL Full Text Search Inaccurate Results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, full-text-search

I've been trying to run a full text search on mysql but I'm not exactly getting the result that I'm supposed to.

I have several entries with "(OBB)" in them. but when I search for "obb" I won't get any results.

The statement I'm using is a really basic one.

```
SELECT * FROM learning_course WHERE MATCH (name, keywords) 
AGAINST ('"obb*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

However, if I was to use a simple `LIKE "%obb%"` I do get the intended result.

Am I missing anything? I've checked with other keywords and it works correctly. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try removing the inner double quotes in your search term, as well as the `*`: `AGAINST ('obb' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.

Comment: Mysql Fulltext search don't search with 3 chars or less. Unless you change ft_min_word_len in the config